# what does this bulb need to work properly in this circuit?

Tags: ac, full-bridge

This is the circuit, before it was working, but not anymore. I have an identical circuit and its ulb still working. I don't know where is the problem.[image: Circuit]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPpZW.jpg)[image][image]

Comment: Are you trying to place the lightbulb on the DC output or the AC Input?

Comment: On the AC input.

Comment: I think it would make sense then to put the bulb in parallel with the AC Input, before the Full Bridge Rectifier.

Comment: No, It works as follows: when a switch between the bulb and the ground closes => the bulb on => the the circuit closes => the optocoupler on.

Comment: You can have the bulb in parallel with the AC input, and have a switch before the bulb/rectifier.

Comment: there is no switch in the schematic diagram

Comment: I'm not going to modify this board like this, while it has been working for years and years.

Comment: There is a switch between the bulb and the ground, I forgot putting it.

Comment: Can we assume that the bulb is not burned out? Also, the circuit can't work as shown. The bulb requires 50 mA to operate at the specified power level, but the 3.3k resistor is going to limit the current to no more than 7.3 mA through the LED (into a dead short).

Comment: @Shaydzmi For a 24V bulb, the resistor values are wrong.  3.3K should be 24 ohms.  470 should be 24 ohms.  This gives 43mA through the bulb, and 3mA through the opto isolator (assuming it's a typical IR led type.)    Also: if the 24V bulb was instead replaced with a 5mA red LED, then the resistor values would be correct.

Comment: not working? what is the purpose of this circuit?

Comment: @Jasen The circuit is part of an electro mechanical system: when the switch closes (located between the bulb and the ground) should happen the following: bulb on + optocoupler on.

Comment: is it intended to detect a bad bulb or to detect switch closure?

Comment: To detect the switch closure.

Comment: Shaydzmi, To work, it would need the supply voltage to be 240V not 24!

Comment: For that the diodes should be 1N4007 and the electrolytic capacitor 22μF 350 WV.

Comment: And the 3.3kΩ resistor rated 1W or more.

Comment: @vu2nan This circuit has been working for years, nothing's changed. And shouldn't be so. I added some photos, I may be wrong giving values.

Comment: What is the definition of "working" here. What should be happening but isn't?

Comment: Working = Lamp on, and the things after the optocoupler are doing their job. The lamp doesn't light up.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to detect switch closure just take your exisiting circuit an connect the bulb in parallell with the bridge rectifier.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, how?

Comment: But I have the same circuit next to it, and it's working just fine.

Comment: Hi Shaydzmi, According to your circuit, the lamp may glow only at the instant of grounding, as the 22μF capacitor charges up to 34V.  That point onwards, the opto-coupler would give a continuous signal that grounding has occurred. In Jasen's circuit the lamp would also give a continuous indication of the grounding.

Comment: @vu2nan, Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: also, with the original circuit if the lamp fails the optcoupler will stop indicating activity.